# Google apps script html template SyntaxError

Tags: google-apps-script, template-engine

Here is a section of my google apps script html template:

```
<? if (filter == "ticket"){ var feedback =  sortFeedbackByDate(getRecentTicketFeedback()); }
   else if (filter == "all"){ var feedback =  sortFeedbackByDate(getAllRecentFeedback()); }
   else { var feedback = getRecentBomgarFeedback(); }
   var percHappy = getNumHappy(feedback) / feedback.length;
   var percOK = getNumOK(feedback) / feedback.length;
   var percSad = getNumSad(feedback) / feedback.length; ?>
```

When calling getCode() on this template, this section is as follows:

```
if (filter == "ticket"){ ; 
  output._ =  '                  <option value=\"'; output._ =  ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()+"?page=1&filter=ticket" ; output._ =  '\">Ticket Feedback</option>\n';
  output._ =  '                  <option value=\"'; output._ =  ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()+"?page=1" ; output._ =  '\">Bomgar Feedback</option>\n';
  output._ =  '                  <option value=\"'; output._ =  ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()+"?page=1&filter=all" ; output._ =  '\">All Feedback</option>\n';
  output._ =  '                ';  } else if (filter == "all" { ; 
  output._ =  '                  <option value=\"'; output._ =  ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()+"?page=1&filter=ticket" ; output._ =  '\">Ticket Feedback</option>\n';
  output._ =  '                  <option value=\"'; output._ =  ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()+"?page=1&filter=all" ; output._ =  '\">All Feedback</option>\n';
  output._ =  '                  <option value=\"'; output._ =  ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()+"?page=1" ; output._ =  '\">Bomgar Feedback</option>\n';
  output._ =  '                ';  } else { ; 
  output._ =  '                  <option value=\"'; output._ =  ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()+"?page=1" ; output._ =  '\">Bomgar Feedback</option>\n';
  output._ =  '                  <option value=\"'; output._ =  ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()+"?page=1&filter=ticket" ; output._ =  '\">Ticket Feedback</option>\n';
  output._ =  '                  <option value=\"'; output._ =  ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()+"?page=1&filter=all" ; output._ =  '\">All Feedback</option>\n';
  output._ =  '                ';  } ;
```

As you can see, in the template the following line is present:

```
else if (filter == "all"){
```

This is seen as this from calling getCode()

```
else if (filter == "all" {
```

This obviously causes a syntax error. Have I made some kind of error here, or is this a bug in the js code generation ?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would say it looks like a bug, except that I tried your snippet and didn't see the bug, and the getCode() results you are showing don't correspond at all to the template snippet you are showing. Can you show the actual code causing the error?

If you are having trouble matching up getCode() to the original template code, try getCodeWithComments() instead.